# How to implement auto-refresh with Redis cache

Tags: .net, caching, redis, stackexchange.redis

MemoryCache has a [Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.set?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) method that lets me specify a delegate that is called before a cache entry is removed from the cache via the `CacheItemPolicy` parameter.

This can be used to [auto refresh the cache](https://underscorehao.net/2019/07/auto-refreshing-cache-in-dotnet/) at regular intervals without employing Hangfire or some other task runner.

How can I implement this in .NET using StackExchange.Redis ?

I have not been able to find any methods in the [Redis command reference](https://redis.io/commands) that would suit my purpose and all the implementations of `ObjectCache` that I have found online throw a `NotSupportedException` in their implementations:

https://github.com/justinfinch/Redis-Object-Cache/blob/master/src/RedisObjectCache/RedisCache.cs
https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v20/dh/to/azure-redis-cache-example.html
https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/pull/72/commits/2930ede272fe09abf930208dfe935c602c1bb510

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing built in Redis.

But, Redis does support [keyspace notifications](https://redis.io/topics/notifications) which provides a way to register for `Expired` event. 
You can register a client that will react on such event and refresh the cache.

Another option is to use [RedisGears](https://redisgears.io) and [register](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgears/functions.html#register) on `expired`--> `register(eventTypes=['exired'])` event such that each time an expire event is triggered your function that runs embedded in Redis will refresh the data.

Comment: I think the problem with that is that there will be a period of time between Expired event being raised and the refreshed data being available when there will be nothing in cache. My understanding is that with `MemoryCache` the cache is still available while the `CacheItemPolicy.UpdateCallback` is processing. Maybe I could use MemoryCache to  store a tiny item that expires before the main RedisCache and use it's expiry to refresh both

Comment: Another pattern is to keep each key twice in Redis once for the data and once just to get the expire in vent and react on it (the second without real value)

Answer (score -1):

The typical pattern in cache is to call cached data and when not found, load it.

```cs
public T Get<T>(string key)
{
    T ret = GetFromRedis<T>(key); // I am not going to go into implementation of GetFromRedis for purpose of this question
    if (ret == null)
    {
        // in the multi-server situation, this lock can be 
        // implemented as UPDATE record lock on DB transaction ***
        lock(_loadLock) 
        {
            ret = GetFromRedis<T>(key);
            if (ret == null)
            {
                ret = DataProvider.Load<T>();
                SetInRedis(key, ret);   
            }
        }
    }
    return ret; 
}
```

*** I wouldn't put too much emphasis on that lock for !!multiple!! servers. Yea, you might end-up loading data twice or more in the first load but your redis `SET` can use `When.NotExists`. This way, actual cache will not be replaced when multiple threads try to do it. So, this is on-demand caching vs constant caching. For example, in large applications, there are parts that not being used. Why populate the cache? Then, users start hitting the part and voila!

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. I already have a read-through cache strategy - with absolute expiry. The problem with that is increased latency each time the cache expires. Using MemoryCache I can avoid that problem (once the application is warmed up) with an auto refresh implemented via CacheItemPolicy. The question is about how I might achieve the same thing using Redis

Comment: I guess, my point was - "do you need to constantly keep stuff in the cache? ... really?" In my system, I currently use `System.Runtime.Caching` (before was enterprise library caching), and cache expires and its blown. Then, it is re-populated on first demand as you see in my answer. Yes, this answer is not about how keep cache filled but rather how not to keep it constantly filled. I am now adding Redis as communication layer to my local cache. Local is so much faster. When data changes, redis will ping local cache provider to purge the key, then reload on the first demand. Keeps it fresh

Comment: I was wondering if your approach is 2 threads, with one data retriever relying for the cache to be there and another taking care of loading. In this case, you must have cache.  My approach is 1 thread responsible for both - loading and retrieving the cache, which has failback to data source and eliminates a need for the separate loading thread.